# android: what's preferred, loading custom font or image?

Tags: android, fonts

What is a best practice when it comes to weird fonts?

I have to show a unique font on a splash page only, it's a .otf font. What's better (if a discriminator for "better" is needed, let's look at it from the point of view of performance, but any feedback is welcome), have a picture of my text on the splash screen (I already learnt I need to provide images for every supported screen size), or to have a font loading throught `Typeface.createFromAssets`()?

I know "what's better" questions are always a bit ambigous, but in this case it's a rather specific question - otherwise I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you call the font you want to use "weird" rather than just "custom", but: if you need to shape lots of text with it, just use the font itself *provided you may do so*. Not every font you pull off the web lets you do what you want just because you found it for free, make sure to do your homework and check whether the font actually has license terms or costs money. If all you need it for is the splash page, then an image might make more sense, provided it's smaller than the font itself. If it's bigger, you might as well save space and use the real font.

Comment: clear answer. yes, "custom" font is better :) The font in question is only used for the splash. I checked and the otf file is 90k, the image from the designer is 20k. So I guess I'll go with the image! Thank you very much.

Comment: just remember to give the image a good pixel density! You don't want to give a "full screen" splash that's less than 240dpi =)